# Angularjs serving a fetched link for download

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.open

I have a div like so:

```
<div ng-click="download(file)">Click me</div>
```

My `download` function then returns a URL that has the file ready to be served. My goal is to open up the url.

```
$scope.download = function(file) {
    $http.post("/fetch/file", {download_id: $stateParams.download_id, file: file }).success(function(data) { 
        window.open(data);
    });
}
```

The `window.open` function doesn't really work with pop up blockers so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions.

I can get past this by doing `window.location.assign(data);` but it still modifies my URL at the top which I am trying not to do.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You could always open it in a modal window with an iframe.

Comment: set headers on server to force download and browser won't change

Comment: try `$window.open(data, '_self')` to trigger file download without opening new tab + always use `$window` service in angular context.